# Spectral Gap of Elliptic Operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, sp.spectral-theory, elliptic-pde, differential-operators

Under what conditions on $a(x)$ and domain $D$, the spectral gap of the elliptic operator $ \nabla \cdot(a(x)\cdot \nabla)$ defined on $D$, can be controlled?

The boundary condition is that the solution at the boundary is zero. Assume that $D$ is a unit ball in $R^{d}$. Since the eigenvalues of this operator are countable and nonnegative, the spectral gap is the difference between its smallest nonzero eigenvalue and zero.

Comment: Do you impose any boundary conditions? What is the dimension of $D$? Please  define precisely what you mean by spectral gap.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu OP has updated the question.

Comment: Well, by the minimax principle the spectral gap of $\nabla\cdot(a\nabla)$ is not smaller than the spectral gap of $\alpha\Delta$, where $\alpha$ is the essential infimum of $M:=\{\xi^* a(x)\xi:\xi \in {\mathbb C}^d\}$; and not larger than $A\Delta$, where $A$ is the essential supremum of $M$. Now, you can control the spectral gap of $\alpha \Delta$ (resp., $A\Delta$) by invoking the literature devoted to spectral geometry of $\Delta$; for instance, the most classical lower bound for the spectral gap of $\Delta$ in terms of the volume of $\Omega$ is the Faber-Krahn inequality.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo: This raises a question as to what happens if the operator is (pointwise) elliptic but not uniformly elliptic.

Comment: Two remarks: (i) Since the spectrum of the operator is contained in $(-\infty,0]$, one should probably speak of the *largest* non-zero eigenvalue rather than of the *smallest* non-zero eigenvalue. (ii) In the important special case where the operator is uniformly elliptic the number $0$ is not a spectral value, so I'm not sure why one would call the distance of $0$ to some spectral value a *spectral gap*.

Comment: @JochenGlueck In principle you're right, but both are die-hard spectral theoretical conventions.